# iOS 8 error opencv

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I am developing an iOS application using opencv. I built my app on target iOS 7 and every thing is OK. I am now moving to iOS 8 beta. When build my app on target 8.0 it comiles and build without any problems, but when I try to use video in my app and show it on UIImage no output appears and I get these warnings -although it was working on iOS 7-:

> Detect with curves[9273:60b] WARNING: -[ isVideoMinFrameDurationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureDevice activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges
>   Detect with curves[9273:60b] WARNING: -[ setVideoMinFrameDuration:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureDevice setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration
>   Detect with curves[9273:60b] WARNING: -[ isVideoMaxFrameDurationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureDevice activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges
>   Detect with curves[9273:60b] WARNING: -[ setVideoMaxFrameDuration:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureDevice setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration

can any one help ?!

Answer (score 0):

If you change  _videoCamera.defaultFPS to 30, it will solve your problem. The reason is you set defaultFPS too high.